# How should I read this file format in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import

I would like to read text files with this structure:

```
FileHeader "WWW Object Text","Coordinate Document"
begin
    FileInfo "Application","XXX"
    FileInfo "SerialNo","XXXX"
    FileInfo "Author","xxxx"
    FileInfo "Company","xxxx"
    FileInfo "Description",
    FileInfo "Coordinate System","ZZZZZ"
end
PointList 
begin
    Point "1",6619195.566,139583.0563,17.3598,"227",,
    Point "2",6619195.1951,139583.12,16.7636,"228",,
    Point "3.1CUL",6618174.0649,141818.0054,17.3889,"612",,
    Point "3.2CUL",6618176.6504,141817.6756,17.4405,"612",,
end
LineList 
AttributeList
```

It seems simple, but I have not figured it out how to read it with `Add delimited text layer`. Does it belong to a known format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that there are 11 lines to the first "Point" line in every file. If so, use those options in "Create a Layer from a Delimited Text File" window:
(You may need to modify X and Y field)

[image]

And then, you need to specify "Coordinate System".

Comment: Awesome! I did not know what was `Escape` for, now it is clear

Comment: "Your" file format seems to be designed to potentially include other geometry types (**cf. LineList**) i guess the import of these objects won't be as easy as for points ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a known file format but if your aim is only to retrieve the points it contains you can certainly copy the part between `begin` and `end` (**pointlist**) and retrieve these data in a csv file.
Unless you want a more automatic procedure (of course)

Comment: Yes, I would like to read them without the need of creating new ones or modifying them

Comment: i suppose i wasn't clear enough ...